# How to deduct the hours with condtion

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Using SQL Server

Table1

```
ID, MinTime, TotalTime, BreakTime

001, 04:00:00, 12:00:00, 00:30:00
002, 04:00:00, 03:00:00, 00:30:00
003, 08:00:00, 07:30:00, 03:30:00
004, 04:00:00, 03:59:59, 01:30:00
```

.

I want to deduct the totaltime-breaktime when totaltime>mintime

```
Condtion:

If Totaltime is greater than mintime then it should deduct the total hours, but it should Maintain the  MinTime
```

For Example:

```
Min time: 05:00:00
Total Time: 06:00:00
BreakTime: 01:30:00
```

Total Time is greater than min time, so we can make (totaltime-Breaktime), it will give output like "04:30:00" (is not right because it should maintain the min time also, so it should deduct 1 Hours only from the break time)

Expected Output

```
ID, MinTime, TotalTime, BreakTime DeductTime

001, 04:00:00, 12:00:00, 00:30:00 11:30:00 (TotalTime is Greater than mintime)
002, 04:00:00, 04:35:00, 01:00:00 04:00:00 (`Here TotalTime is greather than mintime, so it should deduct the breaktime from the total hours, but it should maintain the mintime also)`
003, 08:00:00, 07:30:00, 03:30:00 07:30:00 (TotalTime is less than mintime)
004, 04:00:00, 03:59:59, 01:30:00 03:59:59 (TotalTime is less than mintime)
```

How to make a query for the above condition.

Need Query Help

Comment: There's some inconsistency in your examples. On the last three rows `TotalTime` is less than `MinTime`, yet the very last one shows `DeductTime = 04:00:00 = MinTime` while on the other two lines `DeductTime = TotalTime`. Also, what data type is used for the time values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [CASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) Statement

```
SELECT  ID
        , MinTime
        , TotalTime
        , BreakTime
        , CASE WHEN TotalTime < MinTime THEN TotalTime
               WHEN TotalTime - BreakTime < MinTime THEN MinTime
               ELSE TotalTime
          END AS DeductTime
FROM    Table1
```

> CASE (Transact-SQL)
>   Evaluates a list of conditions and
>   returns one of multiple possible
>   result expressions.

Comment: @Liven, Thanks for your response, I modified my question. can you look at please

Comment: @Gopal: I've edited the answer but putting in more effort to find the solution yourself would do you better service in the long run *(it is Lieven btw, not liven)*.

Comment: <Quote>It always amazes me that people expect me to spend my time answering questions they won't spend their time asking. (George)</Quote>

Answer (score 1):

If your datatype is not datetime and is nvarchar see this reply:

[How to generate the date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883095/how-to-generate-the-date/4884245#4884245)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a user defined function.

```
create function GetTotalHours (@BreakTime datetime,@Totaltime datetime, @MinTime DateTime) returns datetime
as
begin
declare @newTotalTime datetime;
declare @DiffenceInHours int;
set @DiffenceInHours = datediff(HH,@BreakTime,@Totaltime);

if @Totaltime >@MinTime
    begin --If Totaltime is greater than mintime then it should deduct the total hours
        set @newTotalTime=dateDiff(HH,@DiffenceInHours,@Totaltime);
    end
else
    begin--If totaltime is smaller than mintime then it should not deduct the total hours
        set @newTotalTime=@Totaltime;
    end

return @newTotalTime ;
end
go
```

Then select from your table using the udf, something like this ....

```
select dbo.GetTotalHours('2011-02-03 14:51:48.620',
    '2011-02-03 11:51:48.620','2011-02-03 11:51:48.620')
from  [YourSourceTable]
```

Comment: The times shown are amounts, not timestamps, so basically he needs to perform conditional subtracting, something along the route proposed by Lieven. Only the OP's date/time data tend to be of nvarchar type, based on the lot of his/her recent questions. The OP keeps forgetting to mention this fact, as well as being reminded of it.

Comment: @Andriy M: looking at OP's history, he is indeed stretching it. It *appears* like there's no effort whatsoever to find answers by himself.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I modified my question. can you look at please